# Teleporting Multiple People with Command Block in Minecraft Java Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Me and some friend have been working on a project in Minecraft, we are recreating some of the games from Minecraft Championships and having our own personal MCC. I am trying to find a way to teleport all the players at once using a command block, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the following command to teleport all players in the world to the coordinates 0 64 0.

```
/tp @a 0 64 0
```

If you want to teleport all players to the entity named Bob use this command.

```
/tp @a @e[name=Bob, limit=1]
```

Comment: If you are using a generic `target` as the `destination` (such as `@e` or `@a`), you need to specify `limit=1`

Comment: Thanks, didn't catch that. Added.